# Let E and F be events of a sample space S of an experiment, then P(E|F) + P(E'|F) is what?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I tried solving this question and when asked my friends, the answers were totally different. So I came here for a better opinion.

Let $E$ and $F$ be events of a sample space $S$ of an experiment, then $P(E | F) + P(E' | F)$ is:

1. $P(E)$
2. $P(F)$
3. $P(S)$
4. $P(E | F)$

Most of my friends said that the answer is $P(S)$ since it covers both the areas, $E$ and $E'$. I said that it has be to $P(F)$ because the event $F$ has to occur and the other said that since both the events are mutually exclusive, the answer is $P(E | F)$. I'm having a hard time coming to a conclusion on this question. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is $P(S)$.

Comment: How? Could you elaborate?

Comment: $P(E,F)+P(E',F) = P(F)$. Hence $$P(E\mid F)+P(E'\mid F) = P(F)/P(F) = 1 = P(S)$$

Comment: ok, thanks a lot @andrew-zhang.

Comment: In some sense, your intuition that the answer is $P(F)$ is correct, but it is not $P(F)$, it is $\tilde P(F)$ where $\tilde P$ is a probability measure on the new sample space $F$ (see Ross, A First Course in Probability for a tidbit on this)

Comment: Sure, will do that. Thanks for taking the time to explain. :)